# How can I use IntelliJ IDEA editor in my own plugin?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, plugins

I have developed plugin for Intellij Idea that contains code editor. And I want to use Intellij idea internal editor ui implementation, but I don't know how to add it to my window.
Here is XML:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <toolWindow id="Playground" anchor="right" factoryClass="PlaygroundEditor" secondary="true"/>
</extensions>
```

Code:

```
public class PlaygroundEditor implements ToolWindowFactory {
private JPanel basePanel;

@Override
public void createToolWindowContent(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull ToolWindow toolWindow) {
    toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(
            ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance().createContent(basePanel, "", false)
    );

    Document document = EditorFactory.getInstance().createDocument("public static void main(String... args) {\n}");
    document.setReadOnly(false);
    EditorFactory.getInstance().createEditor(document);
    EditorComponentImpl editorComponent = new EditorComponentImpl((EditorImpl) EditorFactory.getInstance().createEditor(document));

    basePanel.add(editorComponent, new GridConstraints());
}
```

Result:

[image]

It doesn't works, I can't type here. Can you help me with it, maybe you have experience with intellij idea api, because current api so poor described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Editor editor = EditorFactory.getInstance().createEditor(document);
JComponent editorComponent = editor.getComponent();
```